# Windows 7 is very slow when the lid of the laptop is closed

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, file-transfer

I was moving a file over the local network using wifi connection in explorer. The label said that approximately 10 minutes of time is remaining. I closed the lid and returned after ten minutes. Almost nothing was downloaded during that ten minutes and I saw the label saying that few hours of time is remaining. And during the time I had been watching it the speed was increasing.
I repeated this experiment several times and watched the graphs visualizing network utilization in Windows task manager.
I saw every time the same result. During the time I was watching the nerwork utilization was approximately 25% of 117Mbps and the graphs were showing that the network utilization druing the time the lid was closed is near to 0%.

What is happening? And why do I need to sit before the computer in order to make it work?

Note that the computer surely wasn't sleeping. I can listen to the music normally when the lid is closed.

Comment: The most basic guess I've got is that maybe closing the lid switches the computer to some kind of low power/low network usage mode or something similar, have you searched around in your Power Settings for any anomaly?

Answer (score 1):

I’d have a look at your power configurations as I believe this may point to that, enter powercfg.cpl and see if it changes when you alter the power settings.

It may also be power saving options on the WIC too so you might want to look into the advanced options in Device Manager, devmgmt.msc.

Answer (score 1):

Windows defaults to putting the machine to sleep when you close the lid. You can change this behaviour to "do nothing" when the lid is closed. Follow these directions from the Microsoft Windows site and you can do it yourself (http://bit.ly/ZkWbbA)

Answer (score 0):

as @ChickenP suggests, there might be an anomaly in your power settings that results in this behaviour.

As you can read [here](http://blog.laptopmag.com/windows-advanced-power-options-explained), try to set your wireless adapter energy saving setting to **maximum performance**. Hopefully that will solve your issue.