# Closing the lid of laptop slows down downloading files

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, download, power-management

I would like to download files from the intelernet on my lenovo laptop with windows 7 when the lid is closed.
Unfortunately the download slows down almost to zero when the lid is closed.

Answers to [almost the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/599810/windows-7-is-very-slow-when-the-lid-of-the-laptop-is-closed) sugest preventing preventing the computer from sleeping and looking to power configuration.

Please advise me what to do. Here is setup telling windows not to sleep: [image: The-computer-is-set-up-to-do-nothing-when-I-close-the-lid picture.]

Here are the advanced power configurations:

[image: advanced power configuration also tells to do no action on closing the lid]

I haven't observed that this problem depends on plugging the laptop to electricity.
Thanks in adcance for any other suggestions and help.

Comment: Or if you want to draw attention to the question, you can bounty it when you have enough rep.

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause might be that the wifi-antennae on laptops most often reside in the screen, so the efficiency of the antennae might be severly reduced by closing the lid, increasing the interference and "shielding" part of the signal, try to see if the same happens when using a cabled connection.

Comment: That would best describe the issue. If not, try a 2nd OS, some Linux and test it. Usually it should not give you a different result if OS is configured properly and if so then it's down to the antenna. Or get a hard-line and test it with that. If there's no slowdown then it's definitely the antenna.